# How to add onclick function to show extra information on a event Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, chap-links-library

How can i add onclick function to a event in Timeline chart.

I am using a service from Almende charts (http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/examples/example01_basis.html), now i want a function when i click on a event to show some extra information for that event.

I have found this function in this example (http://timeglider.com/widget/large.html), as i am not good at javascript i can not implement this in Almende charts scripts.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Graphical Display - SKAI</title>

    <!-- for mobile devices like android and iphone -->
    <meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trego.al/skai/schedule/graph/timeline.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://trego.al/skai/schedule/graph/timeline.css">

    <style type="text/css">
            /* Styles for the page */
        html, body {
            font: 10pt arial;
        }

        #mytimeline {
        }

        #new {
            position: absolute;
            left: 25px;
            top: 8px;

            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            /* Custom styles for the Timeline */
        div.timeline-frame {
            border-color: #5D99C3;

            border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* For Firefox 3.6 and older */
        }
        div.timeline-axis {
            border-color: #5D99C3;
            background-color: #5D99C3;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5D99C3', endColorstr='#3A6DA0'); /* for IE */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#5D99C3), to(#3A6DA0)); /* for webkit browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #5D99C3,  #3A6DA0); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
        }
        div.timeline-axis-grid {
        }
        div.timeline-groups-axis {
            border-color: #5D99C3;
        }
        div.timeline-axis-text {
            color: white;
        }
        div.timeline-groups-text {
            color: #4D4D4D;
        }
        div.timeline-event {
            color: #000;
            max-height:50px;
        }
        div.timeline-event-content {
        font-size:12px;
        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timeline = undefined;
        var data = undefined;

        google.load("visualization", "1");

            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
            function drawVisualization() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'group');
                data.addColumn('string', 'content');
                data.addColumn('datetime', 'start');
                data.addColumn('datetime', 'end');
                data.addRows([

['FORAE','<span onclick="myFunction()">LZ122</span>', new Date( 2013,5,01,14,00,00 ), new Date( 2013,5,01,15,30,00 )], 
['FORAE','<span onclick="myFunction()">LZ101</span>', new Date( 2013,5,01,16,10,00 ), new Date( 2013,5,01,17,50,00 )], 
['FORAE','<span onclick="myFunction()">LZ102</span>', new Date( 2013,5,01,18,40,00 ), new Date( 2013,5,01,20,20,00 )], 
['FORAE','<span onclick="myFunction()">LZ555</span>', new Date( 2013,5,02,04,00,00 ), new Date( 2013,5,02,07,00,00 )]

                ]);

           // specify options
            var options = {
                width:  "100%",
                height: "99%",
                layout: "box",
                axisOnTop: true,
                eventMargin: 15,                    // minimal margin between events
                eventMarginAxis: 0,                 // minimal margin beteen events and the axis
                "min": new Date('2013-06-01'),        // lower limit of visible range
                "max": new Date('2013-06-30'),        // upper limit of visible range
                editable: false,
                showNavigation: true,
                OverlappingGridLines: true
            };

            // Instantiate our timeline object.
            timeline = new links.Timeline(document.getElementById('mytimeline'));

            // Draw our timeline with the created data and options
            timeline.draw(data, options);

            // Set a customized visible range
            var start = new Date(now.getTime() - 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            var end = new Date(now.getTime() + 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            timeline.setVisibleChartRange(start, end);
        }


    </script>

    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    document.getElementById("demo");
         alert("some information: here should the description appear");
    }
    </script>


    </head>

    <body onresize="timeline.redraw();" style="background:#F9F8F6">

    <div id="mytimeline"  style="background:#fff;min-width:900px;"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting this event to fire when you click an element on your web page, the following code should solve your problem:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myButton");
el.onclick = function () {
     alert("some information");
};
```

You will obivously replace the alert message with whatever it is that you are wanting to display to the user.

Comment: well this is working if i want to display the same message in all events, as i have to many events i have connected them with php, mysql to the server. If i will place a echo inside the alert function is not showing me nothing

Comment: is the alert box coming up at all?

Comment: yes, in every event and should have a info for that event, let assume on click will show event title

Comment: try doing... `alert(this.toString());' Let's see what gets populated within the alert message.

Comment: i receive this info [object Window]

Comment: i believe should be something added to the event inside the event row, but the script is not allowing me to do that

Comment: so where is the Title of the Event actually stored? What you could do is add the event title as an attribute of that element on the web page and then get the attribute of whatever event they click on and have it display the title. I'm just not sure where the value is actually being stored at.

Comment: i have updated the script as it should be without a database connection, here {data.addRows} are located the events with the format that should be.

Comment: if you uploaded some where it should work since i have inserted even the source link